# Filter query by site property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2013, query

- I have set a crawled property at the site level using
  `$site.IndexPropertyKey.Add()` and `$site.Properties.Add()`
- I set the value of that property to "somevalue"
- I full crawled.
- I mapped it to a managed property.
- Next, I went to change the query in a content search web part to just return a list of sites that match my new property. I used the query `MyProperty=somevalue`.
- The previous query returns what I want, all sites that have "somevalue" in the "MyProperty" field.

The question: How do I create a query that lets me externalize the "somevalue" part?

Basically I want a query like this. `MyProperty={Site.MyProperty}`. I want this to display all sites that match the same value in "MyProperty" as the current site I am on. If this is confusing, I can explain more.

Comment: can you post script to achive this

Answer (score 2):

I was close. The answer is `ManagedPropertyName:{Site.CrawledPropertyName}`. This will return all sites that match the property bag value of your current site.